# How to check $_POST using substring

Tags: php

i just want to check whether my $_POST has 'Project :' in it or not. 
But its getting failed ! 
Can i know why ?

`if (substr($_POST['project'],0,8) == 'Project :'){
    $project = $_POST['project'];
}`

Comment: Var_dump it so we can see

Comment: you miscounted - substr(...0,8) should be (...0,9)

Comment: Maybe this can be useful to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366730/how-do-i-check-if-a-string-contains-a-specific-word

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following

```
if(strpos($_POST['project'], 'Project :') !== false) {

   $project = $_POST['project'];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I suggest reading the documentation on the [`substr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) function.  The second parameter is the starting position, the third is the length.  That means you can only have an 8 character output.

```
Project :
        ^
123456789
```

You got one character too many.  Try changing the `0,8` to `0,9`

Answer (score 0):

Using the link I provided you in a comment.

If the use of `substr` isn't mandatory, I suggest you to use `strpos` that way:

```
if (strpos($_POST['project'], 'Project :') !== false) {
    $project = $_POST['project'];;
}
```

Hope it helps.